# open fancybox from js.erb file rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have inside a fancybox box is already opened the next link:

```
<%= link_to new_user_board_path(current_user), :method => :get, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "users/boards", :action => "new" }  do%>
```

When I doing click in this link call to file **new.js.erb**

I want close **current fancybox box** and open other new fancybox from **new.js.erb** file. I want add a partial inside new fancybox box:

I have in **new.js.erb**

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

**and now how open the new fancybox?**

I have tried:

```
$.fancybox()
```

but I get:

**The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.**

and I want add this code to the new fancybox:

```
<h1>New board</h1>
<%= render 'formnew' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', user_boards_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you don't actually need to close the current fancybox and open a new one "step-by-step" (using `$.fancybox.close`), it would enough just to bind the link inside the current modal to a fancybox call, for instance

if the first fancybox was opened with this script:

```
$('.fancylink').fancybox({
 // options
});
```

then bind fancybox to the link inside the current fancybox assigning it the same class as the selector of the js call like:

```
<%= link_to new_user_board_path(current_user), :class =>"fancylink", :method => :get, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "users/boards", :action => "new" }  do%>
```

That will call the new content in (a new) fancybox and will close the current at the same time.